# Google App Engine (GAE), Urban Airship, Java, Push notifications. Sample code?

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, push-notification, urbanairship.com

My server is running on GAE (Java), and I'm using Urban Airship service to deliver push notifications.  Of course, everything works fine when I use their web-interface to send a test notification, but I'd like to add a test-button to my GAE app/server to have *it* trigger UA to send the push.

The problem is, all of the examples I've seen so far don't compile against GAE's Java libraries.

Does anyone have any java sample code they'd like to share that build & runs under GAE to trigger a push notification through Urban Airship?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: Urban Airship isn't a requirement.  My goal is for my GAE(java) app to trigger APNS.  I added UA a few days ago, thinking it would help.  However, if your solution gets me direct-from-GAE, or through some other free, reliable service (UA is free-to-start, like GAE), I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some Java sample code that works under GAE and sends a push notification through Urban Airship:

```
URL url = new URL("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

String appKey = "YOUR APP KEY HERE";
String appMasterSecret = "YOUR MASTER SECRET HERE";

String authString = appKey + ":" + appMasterSecret;
String authStringBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(authString.getBytes());
authStringBase64 = authStringBase64.trim();

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringBase64);

String jsonBodyString = "YOUR URBAN AIRSHIP JSON HERE";

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
osw.write(jsonBodyString);
osw.close();

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
// Add your code to check the response code here
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had figured this out and forgotten to come back and post but, yes, your example is pretty much what I needed.  The part I was missing was the setRequestProperty Authorization line -- I had somehow skimmed over that and, of course, it made everything not-work.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer doesn't work for special characters like german umlauts (öäü) under GAE. It works perfectly in the text-environment on my mac with delivery to the iPhone. So I guess it is an encoding problem I just cannot get solved. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the example code to show how to set the encoding on the OutputStreamWriter.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is trying to use Google app engine to send push notification via urbanairship, to iOS devices, this is what finally worked for me! This is for V3 API.

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; //commons-codec-1.6.jar

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(URBAN_AIRSHIP_PUSH_URL);
            String nameAndPassword = DEV_API_KEY+":"+DEV_API_MASTER_SECRET;

            String authorizationHeader = Base64.encodeBase64String(nameAndPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            authorizationHeader = "Basic "+authorizationHeader;

            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
            request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader));
            request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-type", "application/json"));
            request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"));

            logger.info("Authorization header for push:"+authorizationHeader);
            logger.info("PushMessage payload:"+notificationPayload);
            request.setPayload(notificationPayload.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            URLFetchService urlFetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
            HTTPResponse fetchedResponse = urlFetchService.fetch(request);

            if (fetchedResponse.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                logger.warning("Push notification failed:"+new String(fetchedResponse.getContent(), "UTF-8")+
                    "response code:"+fetchedResponse.getResponseCode());
            } else {
                logger.info("PushMessage send success");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "PushMessage failed", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "PushMessage failed", e);
        }
```

Comment: you should mention that `notificationPayload` is the entire json. +1

Answer (score 1):

Because you said *Urban Airship isn't a requirement* let me recommend `java-apns-gae`.

It's an open-source Java APNS library that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.

https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae

Comment: Do you have an example project that uses your Git project on app-engine? I am talking about something similar to the example project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java. For whatever reason, the google project is not working for me. So if you don't mind sharing a simple project that works, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @KatedralPillon I cannot share an example project but you may check out the docs of `java-apns-gae` - it contains some example code. http://zsoltsafrany.github.io/java-apns-gae

Comment: I have already been looking at the docs. No luck. The Google project I mentioned seems similar enough to yours that you could modify it. If ever you can make some time to help some complete strangers, it would help a lot of people. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[urbanairship4j](http://code.google.com/p/urbanairship4j/) (available on Google Code) uses [Google HTTP Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) so works perfectly on AppEngine, Android, etc.